Moving values in pandas df to new column within df, rename column based on str in column
I have a pandas df of data stripped from a pdf. I have already done some considerable wrangling to get it to this point. There are about 100 chemical concentrations at about 10 sites, and in separate rows, a lab note for each of them denoting info from the tests corresponding to each site. I would like to add the unit  (various units) into the column name and move the lab note (a,b,c,d,e in example, vary in my data) into the row for its respective location. Please see image below.
current df vs desired df layout
Previously the lab note was in the row directly under its respective lab test - after an outer join with a df of the coordinates of the test sites, it was rearranged as seen in the example I posted.
I am inexperienced with loops, and certainly need a loop solution due to the number of columns in my data.
Thank you.
Attempted to add unit to column name using
df.rename(columns={'chem1': 'chem1'+df.chem1.iloc(index of units row),repeat ad infinitum}, inplace=True)
Do not know where to start with loops for either problem

Images of data are not accessible and not reproducible. You must provide a [mre] (as text, or better as code) to be able to set up your example.

You could use iloc to separate the rows, then
StartColumns = df.columns
newColumns = df.iloc[5:10, 3:]
NewColumnNames = [StartColumns[i] + "_LQ" for i in range(3, len(StartColumns))]
newColumns.columns = NewColumnNames
# Don't change the first 3 column names
ColNames = [StartColumns[i] if i < 3 else "_".join(StartColumns[i], df.iat[10, i]) for i in range(len(StartColumns))]
df.columns = ColNames
FinalDf = pd.concat(df, newColumns, ignore_index = True, axis = 1)

Then to re-order the columns, you'll need to use something like
AllCols = ColNames[:3]
for i in range(2 * len(NewColumnNames)):
    # Integer division truncates, so we can take the first relevant index 
    # from our renamed columns, then the first from our new columns
    if i % 2 == 0:
        AllCols.append(ColNames[3 + int(i/2)])
    else:
        AllCols.append(NewColumnNames[int(i/2)])
FinalDf = FinalDf[AllCols]

This code will not be the fastest, but it should do what you're looking for.

iloc is not deprecated - see the docs for what has changed.

@user19077881 I've quoted the documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

... which confirms that a very specific feature of iloc was deprecated not the function itself and this does not affect your code in any way It relates to passing a callable function which returns a Tuple.

Ah ok, I've misread it. I've updated the answer

see answer reply, thank you

First part worked with minor tweaks - used pd.merge outer join to create FinalDf as concat returned error on number of args
In ColNames line adjusted to
oldNames = [StartColumns[i] if i < 4 else "".join(StartColumns[i]+"_"+df.iat[32, i]) for i in range(len(StartColumns))]

, your solution added underscores between every letter l_i_k_e_s_o_
Still working through second part
